# Como imprimir acentos em Lua

Tags: lua

Estou começando a aprender lua agora, e não consigo imprimir acentos

```
print("Olá mundo")
```

retorna

```
Ol├í mundo
```

tanto no terminal do VS Code quanto no powershell, existe uma maneira de consertar isso?

Answer (score 4):

Tem a ver com encoding -
Você pode ou criar seu arquivo fonte Lua no encoding usado pelo terminal - ou usar um programa de terminal que funcione com utf-8

no windows, uma das formas pode ser usar o aplicativo 'terminal' que você pega na Windows Store oficial. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Mas mais importante do que "fazer funcionar" - você precisa entender o que é codificação de textos, senão não conseguirá fazer programas que funcionem cros-plataforma ou troquem dados com sistemas em rede sem destruir todos os caracteres acentuados.

Uma boa leitura para entender isso é esse artigo, de 2003, de autoria do criador do stackoverflow: http://augustoberziner.blogspot.com/2010/04/o-minimo-absoluto-que-cada.html .

[continuando] - depois que entender isso, e ver a documentação do Lua, vai ver que a linguagem realmente trabalha com "bytes": isso é o texto qu aprece no código fonte é considerado "já codificado". Em contraste com linguagens como Java ou Python que tem um runtime mais "gordinho", e trabalham com texto "agnóstico" a codificação, e podem fazer a codificação de forma transparente ou explícita na hora de imprimir ou de escrever em um arquivo.

A implicação disso é que a codificação que for usada no editor para escrever seu código é sempre a mesma que vai ser usada na impressão. O seu editor está configurado para utf-8 (dá pra saber por pistas como "cada caractere acentuado vira dois caracteres no terminal") , mas mesmo se estivesse na codificação normal do Windows - latin-1 para Windows em português, ainda seria diferente da codificação do terminal, que por questões históricas é CP-852 - ou seja, os acentos sairiam errado do mesmo jeito.

Em Lua, para poder mudar a codificação, tem que ser feito uso de uma biblioteca externa.

Answer (score 0):

Não é bem uma resposta...

- Sugiro que instales o lua 5.3 (que tem melhor suporte para unicode)
- Em linux isso corre perfeitamente. Não uso nem conheço windows mas:

  - Sugiro que arranjes um bom terminal para windows (o comando de linha
    default do windows é velhíssimo e péssimo)
  - A tendência geral é usar unicode, permitindo texto com acentos,
    caracteres matemáticos, símbolos gregos, russos, etc.
    Em windows é possível configurar o default encoding (via registry também
    se pode configurar encoding/locales mesmo do velho command-line)

> In Windows 10 I've managed to permanently solve this
> by going to the system's Language settings, selecting Administrative
> language settings, clicking Change system locale... and checking the
> Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support box and then
> restarting my pc